# Why this php apache_request_headers doesn't work on IIS 7

Tags: php, apache, iis

This works on Apache, why it doesn't seem to work on IIS 7 ?

```
if(!function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
    function apache_request_headers() {
        $headers = array();
        foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
            if(substr($key, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
                $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))))] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $headers;
    }
}

function getCurrentPageUrl() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}    

$a =  apache_request_headers();

$pos = strrpos($a["User-Agent"], "REBOL");
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars(print_r($_SERVER, true)), "</pre>"` to your question?

Comment: Be aware: This won't catch all header fields, like "Content-Type" or "Content-Length" because they are not prefixed with "HTTP_" in $_SERVER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Apache specific, looking at the Docs.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

Comment: He provides a fallback mechanism for when the function isn't available, looking at the code.

Comment: True, I misread. Slightly unclear though, asking why an apache specific method doesn't work under IIS, even if you have created it if it doesn't exist.