# php get_headers is very slow (takes infinite!) when it requests the URI of current page

Tags: php, iis, header

Why it takes an infinite amount of time for this ?

```
function getCurrentPageUrl() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}    

$headers = get_headers(getCurrentPageUrl());
```

Comment: What is returned in `$pageURL`?

Comment: Does your system configuration allow the server to talk to itself? Some firewalls won't, and if it's silently dropping packets on the floor, your script will wait until something times out, or forever.

Comment: @Neal the current php url page. That function works no problem with it. Problem is with get_headers

Comment: @Marc B Oh do you think it's Windows Firewall what should I do then ?

Comment: Are you sure? double check what is being put into `get_headers(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a recursive request. The problem is that you are requesting to load this script and the script which is loading is trying to load it in its self an so on and so on :)

Comment: Oh really :) Well I was trying to find a substitute for this on Apache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359352/why-this-php-apache-request-headers-doesnt-work-on-iis-7 which doesn't work on IIS.

Comment: What I want in final is just to get the user agent !

Comment: You can just get it from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: @Karolis: That'd be the user agent of the person requesting the script. I think OP wants the user agent that PHP will identify itself as.

Comment: @Marc B, I don't think so because PHP's user agent identity is a known and fully controllable thing by a developer. Why would he need to get thing which he knows? :)